# Request to Google Text-To-Speech API

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, google-translate

I have this URL: `http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello+world`
When I put it to the address bar in a browser and hit enter, I get mp3 file with synthesized speech saying "Hello world". Everything is correct.

But now I have a link in HTML that redirects to this URL, like this:

```
<a href="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello+world">Link</a>
```

When I click this link, I don't get a file but an error (simple QuickTime logo). Could anyone explain me why is it so and how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation is that Google restricts the usage of this service: according to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10075876/625158), Google returns a 404 error if the HTTP request contains a [Referer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) other than an empty string.

When you type the URL in the address bar, it's ok because no Referer URL is transmitted to Google. When you click on a hyperlink, you have a referer and Google blocks your request.

**NB:** I tested your URL (see [here](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello%20world)), and it worked. I suspect that it was only because I have tried before by typing the URL in my address bar, and the resource was still in my browser cache or in my audio plugin (VLC) cache.

**NB2:** See [here](http://weston.ruter.net/2009/12/12/google-tts/) for a workaround.

Comment: What browser are you using? When I try to open your link with firefox, I only get an empty QuickTime logo and when I open it with Opera, I get an error stating that such page doesn't exist. Strange thing, because when I hit enter while having the same address specified in address bar, I'm getting a proper file.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 16 and the sound is played with VLC plugin. I tried with Google Chrome (with default sound player) and it works too... It seems to be an issue with Apple Quicktime Player plugin. What browser are YOU using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox and Opera. I tried on other PC and result is the same.