# Google Translate API - No Access Control Origin with Text to Speech

Tags: javascript, api, cross-domain, cors, google-translate

I posted this question on SO to get Google Translate Text-To-Speech to work.

[Google Translate API text-to-speech: http requests forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599797/google-translate-api-text-to-speech-http-requests-forbidden)

I was told I needed a key and to enable billing. I've since done that. I know billing is enabled because, using their [specified endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest) for words-only translations (not narrated speech) (`GET https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&q=Hello%20world`), I'm able to get a response both in DHC and in my application `$.get`:

[image]

In my original question (above), I was told If I get an API key, I would no longer be blocked from getting text-to-speech. I tested the request for Text-to-speech in DHC and Postman:

https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?key=*myKeyHere*&ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=你好

And got a 200:

[image]

Excellent. However, in my application, I make a `get` request:

```
    $.get('https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?key='+myKey+'&ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello+world',
        function (returned_data) {
```

I get blocked:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Why is this?

Comment: Well, Its a security from within your browser. If the response of your request doesn't contain the domain from which your requesting Or ' * ' in the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header, The browser prevents your scripts from reading it.

Comment: And when you have key probably *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header will allow you from only the specific domain..