# Hide referrer header in API request

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, cross-domain, referrer

I need to make requests to Google Translate Text-To-Speech API. I have an enabled key but keep getting blocked by No Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've posted more about it here:

[Google Translate API - No Access Control Origin with Text to Speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929518/google-translate-api-no-access-control-origin-with-text-to-speech)

The following sources, http://weston.ruter.net/2009/12/12/google-tts/ and [Request to Google Text-To-Speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883330/request-to-google-text-to-speech-api) say that

> Google returns a 404 error if the HTTP request contains a Referer
>   header other than an empty string.

Given a request like:

```
    $.get('https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?key='+myKey+'&ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello+world',
        function (returned_data) {
```

How do I hide or remove the referrer header so I'm not blocked?

[this source](https://href.li/) says to put `https://href.li/...` in front. So I changed it to:

```
$.get('https://href.li/?https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?key='+key+'&ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=你好',
```

And am still blocked.

---

**Server-Side attempt:** No response.

[This blog](http://www.konradkiss.com/2012/01/embedding-text-to-speech-into-html5_18.html) provides a server-side script which sets the referrer to an empty string. He says:

> This gets the information from that access point and spits it out right away. But before it requests the data using file_get_contents, the Referer header is set to an empty string.

*/php/testPHP.php:*

```
$qs = http_build_query(array("ie" => "utf-8","tl" => $_GET["tl"], "q" => $_GET["q"]));
$ctx = stream_context_create(array("http"=>array("method"=>"GET","header"=>"Referer: \r\n")));
$soundfile = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?".$qs, false, $ctx);

header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

echo($soundfile);
```

*index.php (root):*

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" style="display:none;">
            <source src="/php/testPHP.php?translate_tts?tl=en&q=the%20brown%20fox%20jumped%20over%20the%20lazy%20dog." type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

*tail -f apache error logs:*

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tl in /Users/myname/Sites/app/melonJS-dev/testPHP.php on line 4, referer: http://melon.localhost/
>
> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&q=the+brown+fox+jumped+over+the+lazy+dog): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n in /Users/myname/Sites/app/melonJS-dev/testPHP.php on line 6, referer: http://melon.localhost

*tail -f access log:* Shows the `tl` param getting passed in with a 200:

> GET
>   /testPHP.php?translate_tts?tl=en&q=the%20brown%20fox%20jumped%20over%20the%20lazy%20dog
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 -

---

**JSONP Attempt:** so I thought perhaps wrapping the return object in a `<script>` would solve the issue. I get no response.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?key='+key+'&ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=你好',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error");
        },
        success: function(json) {
            alert("success");
        }
        });
```

---

**HTML/JS text-to-speech attempt:** 404 block

js:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('a.say').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var text = $('input[name="text"]').val();
                text = encodeURIComponent(text);
                console.log(text);
                //var url = 'https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?&ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=' + text;
                var url = 'https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=' + text + '&tl=en';
                $('audio').attr('src', url).get(0).play();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

html:

```
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <a href="#" class="say">Say it</a>

    <audio src="" class="speech" hidden></audio>
```

Following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOtkNxmg9QY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your PHP script is failing:**

If you take a look at your error response from PHP:

```
PHP Warning: file_get_contents(https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&q=the+brown+fox+jumped+over+the+lazy+dog)
```

You'll notice that the url `file_get_contents` is requesting does not contain a `tl` parameter. This is causing a 404 to be returned. You can visit the page directly in your browser:

https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&q=the+brown+fox+jumped+over+the+lazy+dog

The above returns a 404 response :(

https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&q=the+brown+fox+jumped+over+the+lazy+dog&tl=en

But after we add a nice new shiny `tl=en` parameter, it works :).

Comment: I'm passing in the tl param, `testPHP.php?translate_tts?tl=en...`, the php `http_build_query` seems to be the issue here when I pass in the params: `http_build_query(array("ie" => "utf-8","tl" => $_GET["tl"], "q" => $_GET["q"]))`. It's not recognizing that index. Access logs show the `tl` param being passed in correctly. See edit

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/h4Lvp/, 
You can overwrite header values by calling `setRequestHeader` .

But, some headers are blocked to be overritten by the browsers.

```
/*global jQuery*/
(function ($) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        "beforeSend": function(xhr) {
            // Works fine.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", {
                toString: function() {
                    return "";
                }
            });
            // Logs error on Chrome (probably others) as "Refused to set unsafe header "Referer".
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Referer", {
                toString: function() {
                    return "";
                }
            });
        }
    });
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/",
        dataType: "html"
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("<div>").text("ajax success").appendTo("body");
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you need to write server side program which transmits the request to google. browser -> transmiter(executs http request w/o Referer) -> google api

Comment: this blog, http://www.konradkiss.com/2012/01/embedding-text-to-speech-into-html5_18.html, gives a `PHP` script at the bottom. I tested it but it failed. See edit