# Google Translate API Text to speech - setting encoding for non-roman characters

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, google-translate

I'm using Google Translate's unofficial Text-to-speech API (I've posted more info on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929518/google-translate-api-no-access-control-origin-with-text-to-speech)).

The API endpoint looks like: `https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello%20World`

Making traditional API requests for words, I get No-access-control-origin and 404 blocks. To get around this, I've followed [the php script in this blog](http://www.konradkiss.com/2012/01/embedding-text-to-speech-into-html5_18.html) which strips out the referrer before making the request (more info on my attempts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929663/hide-referrer-header-in-api-request)).

I'm able to get English to work, but I need this to work for Chinese. Unfortunately, when I pass in something like 你好, the voice seems to narrate gibberish. However, if you add this directly to your browser, it narrates perfectly.

[https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=你好](https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD)

**HTML**:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" style="display:none;">
    <source src="testPHP.php?translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=你好" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

**testPHP.php**:

```
<?php
//https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=' + text + '&tl=en
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$params = http_build_query(array("ie" => $_GET['ie'],"tl" => $_GET["tl"], "q" => $_GET["q"]));
$ctx = stream_context_create(array("http"=>array("method"=>"GET","header"=>"Referer: \r\n"))); //create and return stream context
$soundfile = file_get_contents("https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?".$params, false, $ctx); //reads file into string (string with params[utf-8, tl, q], use include path bool, custom context resource headers)

header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

echo($soundfile);
```

**tail -f apache access_logs** shows:

> GET /testPHP.php?translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD HTTP/1.1" 200 13536

This seems okay. As you can see, the `q` query param value, 你好, has been converted. This is fine because it still works if you put it in the browser:

https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD

**tail -f apache error_logs** shows:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ie in
>   /Users/danturcotte/Sites/personal_practice/melonJS-dev/testPHP.php on
>   line 4, referer: http://melon.localhost/

I'm not sure how this is happening, or if it's contributing to screwing up the pronunciation. I'm thinking that the words may be reading off parts of the `ie` index?

The query params from the browser side seem to be registering,

[image]

And as you can see from the apache access_logs, `ie=utf-8` param is being set fine.

So my questions are:

- I've added `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` to my `testPHP.php` file to ensure that the encoding is going through fine. Could this be contributing to the problem?
- I'm building the URI query string as such: `$params = http_build_query(array("ie" => $_GET['ie'],"tl" => $_GET["tl"], "q" => $_GET["q"]));`, so how can there be an undefined index `ie`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your URL:

```
GET /testPHP.php?translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD
```

You have two question marks, which means that PHP will get:

```
Array 
( 
[translate_tts?ie] => utf-8 
[tl] => zh-CN 
[q] => 你好 
)
```

Instead you need to do something like:

```
GET /testPHP.php?translate_tts=value&ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD
```